# Checkbuttons aren't working inside function

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I have a bunch of checkbuttons, with some on and some off by default. I'm having an issue where if I put the checkbuttons inside the function they aren't on by default like they should be.

Here's the working code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

integer = IntVar(value=1)
Checkbutton(root, text="Should be on by default", variable=integer).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Here's the not working code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def main():
    integer = IntVar(value=1)
    Checkbutton(root, text="Should be on by default", variable=integer).grid()

main()
root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is?

Comment: In your second example, the `IntVar` is referenced only by a local variable, and vanishes at the end of the function.  Without the var, the Checkbutton has nowhere to store its state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you see the window, `integer` no longer exists and the checkbox shows as unchecked for lack of a variable to store its state.

Compare:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def main():
    global integer
    integer = IntVar(value=1)
    Checkbutton(root, text="Should be on by default", variable=integer).grid()


main()
root.mainloop()
```

The `global integer` tells Python that this `integer` should be defined at the 'global' level and thus it stays around after the function.

By the way, it's bad practice to name a variable after its type - try picking a name that represents what its value means, instead of describing its type.

You shared some additional code with a similar problem (only repeating the elements that matter):

```
from tkinter import *


def change_job_skills(name):
    top_window = Toplevel(root)
    # ..
    skill_dictionary = {}
    # ..
    row_ = 2
    column_ = 0
    # ..
    job_focuses_dictionary = {}
    for key in sorted(job_focuses_dictionary.keys()):
        Checkbutton(top_window, text=key.strip(""),
                    variable=job_focuses_dictionary[key]).grid(row=row_, column=column_, sticky=W)
    # ..
    # no definition was provided of actually_change_job_skills, but it's not important here
    Button(top_window, text='Submit',
           command=lambda: [actually_change_job_skills(skill_dictionary, name),
                            top_window.destroy()]).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    # no reference is made to `job_focuses_dictionary` in a way that survives the function


root = Tk()
change_job_skills("Community Engagement")
root.mainloop()
```

Although both `skill_dictionary` and `job_focuses_dictionary` are used in the code of `change_job_skills`, `skill_dictionary` is used in the definition of a lambda function, which is then passed as the `command` argument for `Button`. Since the button will need to call that function later, a reference to the lambda is saved inside it and since the function body of the lambda references `skill_dictionary`, the dictionary survives the function returning.

However, `job_focuses_dictionary` is only referenced as `job_focuses_dictionary[key]`, retrieving a value from it - the dictionary itself isn't passed to anything that maintains a reference to it outside the function, so when the function returns, the dictionary is garbage-collected.

Same problem, but a bit harder to spot. (@acw1668 pointed it out in the comments as well)

Note that I also renamed your parameter `Name` to `name`, you should reserve capitalised names for types and lowercase names for variables, in line with Python standard naming, which helps future you and others more quickly read and understand your code. Nothing to do with the problem though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm actually having this problem on a larger scale and was hoping that your answer would fix my problem, but I'm still just left puzzled. [Here's a link to the .py](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E5ibSBY1_R7gCkfEGU4cMtzeSMrkymrZ/view?usp=sharing). For some reason the first half, the skills, work perfectly (despite being defined in the function. The second half, the job focuses, don't work at all. Administration should be checked off by default but it isn't. Mind taking a look at it?

Comment: @Friend_Slayer666 It is because the variable `skill_dictionary` used for the first half (the skills) is still referenced by the lambda function for `Submit` button, so it is not garbage collected after the function exits.

Comment: I hope the added information makes the problem more clear. Also not that you can have an entire connected graph of objects surviving a function, all referencing each other, as long as only one of them ends up being references outside the function, they all survive. That's often not a good thing though, due to side effects and possible issues with memory usage (for larger data structures, or ones that are created very frequently), make sure that's what you want to happen.

Comment: @Grismar thanks for the detailed explanation. It makes sense but I would never have thought of it. I'll just add job_focuses_dictionary to the lambda.